# Complete JFXPanel to image

Tags: java, html, image, javafx, graphics

I want to take a snapshot of a website without any video, so it's just plain text with some css and pictures.

I am using a WebView (which is the scene of the JFXPanel) to load the website and then save it via

```
WritableImage image = scene.snapshot(new WritableImage(1920, 1080));
BufferedImage bufferedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null);
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", file);
```

(where "scene" is the scene of the JFXPanel)

but the saved image just displays a part of the website, instead of the complete content (see picture).

[image]

How do I ensure/enforce that the dimensions of the image matches the dimensions of the JFXPanel content and everthing is visible?

Complete Code:

```
package renderer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class HtmlRenderer extends Application {
    private JFXPanel jfxPanel;
    private WebView webView;

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        webView = new WebView();

        webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
                new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
                        if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                            HtmlRenderer.this.toImage(jfxPanel.getScene());
                            try {
                                Platform.exit();
                                HtmlRenderer.this.stop();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

        jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(webView));

        this.updateView("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
    }

    private void toImage(Scene scene) {
        WritableImage image = scene.snapshot(new WritableImage(1920, 1080));

        // TODO: save in matching dir using proper filename
        File file = new File("D:/workspace/SiteChecker/test.png");

        try {
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null);
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: exception handling
        }
    }

    public void updateView(String url) {
        webView.getEngine().load(url);
    }

    private void reloadView() {
        webView.getEngine().reload();
    }

}
```

Comment: The above code exactly as-is results in a blank white page on Java 8 (tried both OpenJDK and Oracle).

Comment: @DarrellTeague did you see the accepted answer? I was also working with Java 8, but only Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution, but it's far from perfect and not really perfomant.
However, nothing else works for me.
The trick is to load the website once, determine width and height of the site. The second time I set the preferred size of the Webview to the determined values and load the website again with the new size. I think it's because the first time only the visible part is rendered.

The width and height can be determined with javascript, e.g.:

```
private int getPageWidth(WebView webView) {
    String script = "Math.max(" +
            "document.body.scrollWidth, document.body.offsetWidth," +
            "document.documentElement.clientWidth, document.documentElement.scrollWidth," +
            "document.documentElement.offsetWidth );";

    WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();

    int maxWidth = (int) engine.executeScript(script);
    return maxWidth;
}
```

For some reason some websites have a funny end/bottom i.e. there is a lot of empty space.